# Found an error in my logistic regression program

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y,min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y,X,mesh_step_size= 10,10,2,9,1,7,10,10

def visualize(c,x,y):
  global min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y,X
  min_x,max_x = ...
  min_y,max_y = ...

x_vals,y_vals = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min_x,max_x, mesh_step_size))

    # Run the classifier on the mesh grid
output = c.predict(np.c_[x_vals.ravel(), y_vals.ravel()])
    # Reshape the output array
output = output.reshape(x_vals.shape)

    # Create a plot
plt.figure()
    # Choose a color scheme for the plot
plt.pcolormesh(x_vals, y_vals, output, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    # Overlay the training points on the plot
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=75, edgecolors='black',
linewidth=1, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
    
# Specify the boundaries of the plot
plt.xlim(x_vals.min(), x_vals.max())
plt.ylim(y_vals.min(), y_vals.max())
    # Specify the ticks on the X and Y axes
plt.xticks((np.arange(int(X[:, 0].min() - 1), int(X[:, 0].max() + 1),
1.0)))
plt.yticks((np.arange(int(X[:, 1].min() - 1), int(X[:, 1].max() + 1),
1.0)))
plt.show()
```

I got this error pls help!!!!!!!!!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\AI using Python\Logistic Regression 2.py", line 11, in 
x_vals,y_vals = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min_x,max_x, mesh_step_size))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: The error simply states that `np.meshgrid` returns only a single `ndarray` while you try to unpack it into two.  You can check https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html to see how to return multiple ndarrays at the output

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing out the second argument for `np.meshgrid()`.
Change:

```
x_vals,y_vals = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min_x,max_x, mesh_step_size))
```

to:

```
x_vals,y_vals = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min_x,max_x, mesh_step_size), np.arange(min_y, max_y, mesh_step_size))
```

Comment: Found at line 14   output = c.predict(np.c_[x_vals.ravel(), y_vals.ravel()])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'predict'

Comment: Does `c` contain your logistic regression model? You have to call `predict()` on the variable that contains the trained model, maybe you've passed the wrong arguments. I need the full code to help. Can you include it in the question?